# POSIX call for stack memory allocation

Tags: memory, stack, posix, allocation

is there any syscall/function defined in POSIX (POSIX:2008) which allocates memory on the stack, rather than the heap?

I was not able to find anything but alloca, which is not officially included in the POSIX documents.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't actually need `alloca` any more since C99 provides variable length arrays, which give you the same functionality (mostly).

You should look into using that. I would consider that even better than a POSIX solution since it's part of the "primary" standard.

Comment: Generally, allocating memory on the stack is bad practice and should be avoided anyway. I'm not writing any code requiring allocating memory on the stack space, but am rather wondering if something like this exists as I haven't been able to find it. Also, whilst doing it is bad practice, it's generally possible as Wikipedia shows it with alloca, so there has to be something like this defined too.

Comment: @Ionic: last year's nasty vulnerability in glibc `fnmatch` due to `alloca` should serve as a warning to anyone wanting to use this backwards and dangerous practice.

Comment: Allocating memory on the stack is not "bad", given it is of reasonable size, the function isn't recursive, and a pointer to the memory doesn't need to be returned. It's better to avoid blanket statements like that because they can mislead the inexperienced into believing it is an absolute rule. Avoiding stack allocation in all cases would lead to unnecessary use of the heap, which is slower.